# Regex- match on a specific string with any two digit integer in it?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of filenames that look like this:
`red.t<0 padded int>z.white.blue<0 padded int>.ab00.txt2`
For example:

```
red.t01z.white.blue12.ab00.txt2
red.t02z.white.blue45.ab00.txt2
red.t03z.white.blue09.ab00.txt2
```

I want to match on this sequence, for any two digit number. The `00` near the end is constant, and it shouldn't match on any other values there. ie, this wouldn't match `red.t03z.white.blue09.ab01.txt2`.

I tried `red.t[0-9]*z.white.blue[0-9]*.ab00.txt`, but that only works when I have the first `[0-9]*` in there, the second one makes it no longer match. What is the solution to this?

Comment: I think it could be like this `^red\.t[0-9]{2}z\.white\.blue[0-9]{2}\.ab00.txt2$` https://regex101.com/r/lt5pWr/1

Comment: Have you tried making those `[0-9]{2}` (or `\d{2}`) if you're explicitly saying they must both be 2 digits?

Comment: `red.t\d{2}z.white.blue\d{2}.ab00.txt` worked perfectly- if someone adds an answer with this then I will accept it!

Comment: @Thefourthbird, you missing an escape on the last dot. And you should post as answer.

Comment: @JvdV You are right :) I have added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use anchors to assert the start and end of the string, escape the dot to match it literally and use a quantifier `0-9[{2}` to match 2 digits.

```
^red\.t[0-9]{2}z\.white\.blue[0-9]{2}\.ab00\.txt2$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UzUH4S/1)

Comment: Or `^red\.t\d{2}z\.white\.blue\d{2}\.ab00\.txt2$`

Comment: so it's only the ab00 that needs to trigger a match?  So...https://regex101.com/r/WrmVqB/1